# how could i call server api from client app in monorepo in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, rest, monorepo

Below is my project structure where i am making a website in a monorepo. the first directory `server` is an ExpressJs restful API. and second directory `client` is an reactJs app which is made with `create-react-app`. i using `Turborepo` for this monorepo which i have configured successfully. But i don't know how to call the server APIs routes inside the client app. could anyone guide me i am new to this.

```
monorepo
|---server
|   |---api
|   |   |---controllers
|   |   |---middleware
|   |   |---models
|   |   |---routes
|   |---server.js
|   |---package.js
|
|---client
|   |---src
|   |   |---App.js
|   |   |---index.js
|   |---package.js
|
|---package.json
|---turbo.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two apps should be separate apps within the monorepo so they should be run independently.

So let's assume the React App runs on localhost:3000 and the Express App runs on localhost:4000 and you have post route for /submit, the React app would just need to use Fetch or Axios to make a post request to http://localhost:4000/submit like you normally would.

I have [this article](https://tuts.alexmercedcoder.com/2021/8/api_calls_react/) on how to make API calls from React.

If this isn't the issue, can you post any of the following:

- A link to the repo
- What you have tried and the results
- text of any error messages

These would help get a better diagnosis.